# External (CDN) location images only for multiple domain stores

Tags: magento2, product-images, media, base-url, cdn

I have multiple stores on multiple domains (all single store magento installs) that use a lot of the same product images. I want to store all the images in a single location and let the different stores (on different domains) fetch the images from that location.

I can redirect all media by using "Secure Base URL for User Media Files" which works, but I want only the product images to be shared and not all media.

I also don't know how this works regarding the "cache/" subfolder since magento looks for that folder.

Any tips how I can get this working? This would save me a huge amount of server disk space on the individual stores.

Comment: Do you have set up diff Magento setup with different databases or one Magento with multiple websites and store views?

Comment: @BhaveshPrajapati no, it's just "regular" single store shops on different domains, they are not multistores.